# How to remove DevExpress completely from project?

Tags: devexpress

I mistakenly put the DevExpress control (checkBox) on my Winforms in VB project, but I removed it later from project.

Now when I copy that project to my colleague's machine, and when I try to rebuild it it says:

> *Could not resolve ... in licences.licx...*

How can I resolve this? It's very important project to me!

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have licences.licx file in resources of project as embedded resource. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In Properties folder there's a file called licences.

You should find the following line:

```
DevExpress.XtraEditors.CheckEdit, DevExpress.XtraEditors.v12.1, Version=12.1.7.0, Culture=neutral.........
```

(It might be different nums but you get the point...).

Delete line and rebuild!